# One dimensional sparse tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to pass in a one-dimensional sparse vector to Tensorflow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    indices = np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.int64)
    values = np.array([1.5, 3.0], dtype=np.float32)
    shape = np.array([2], dtype=np.int64)
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={
        x: tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)}))
```

This code throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(?, ?)'
```

Am I passing the shape wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices should be of size `(2,1)`. So change the indices to: `indices = np.array([[0], [1]], dtype=np.int64)`. The below code works:

```
x = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   indices = np.array([[0], [1]], dtype=np.int64)
   values = np.array([1.5, 3.0], dtype=np.float32)
   shape = np.array([2], dtype=np.int64)
   print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={
      x: tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)}))

#Output
#4.5
```